# Modify a method parameter value using aspectj in Scala

Tags: scala, aspectj

I have a situation where I need to modify the method parameter value using aspectj in scala. I am using @Before annotation to get the fields.

```
 @Before("execution (* com.myapp.EmployeeController.delete(..))")
  def checkIfWorkflowEnabled(joinPoint: ProceedingJoinPoint): Object = {
    //get the fields and modify oen field
    //check some condition and if success, update the isActive field to false
    //then proceed with what was going on before
  }
```

My Controller method:

```
def delete(id:Long, isActive:Boolean)= {
???
}
```

But I am not able to update the field 'isActive' using aspectj.

EDIT:

As Andy said, I understood that we can modify the method args only in around method. Now, I have another doubt. In around method, will the aspect be executed before and after the actual method invocation? How can I modify the method args before the delete method execution and then just proceed as usual. And after completion of the delete method, invoke some other method.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before() and after() advice cannot modify what is going to happen at a joinpoint, they can merely observe it. around() advice will do what you need. Something like:

```
void around(long l,boolean b): execution(* delete(..)) && args(l,b) {
  if ((l%2)==0) {
    proceed(l,b);
  } else {
    proceed(l,!b);
  }
}
```

Sorry I wrote it in code style, I'm just more familiar with that. This is possible with annotation style but you'll need to use the additional variable `ProceedingJoinPoint` to call proceed on: http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/ataspectj-pcadvice.html

Comment: So does Around get executed twice for every method. I mean, the same aspect method will be executed before and after the delete() method execution, right ?

Comment: no, the around advice takes over at the point where the original thing would execute, it then has the option to run what that joinpoint was going to do by calling proceed. If it didn't call proceed then what was originally supposed to happen doesn't occur.

Comment: Andy, Sorry for asking question again. I think I didn't make the question clear. What I want to do is, after the aspect intercepts the call, i want to modify the method parameter and execute the method as usual. After that method is executed successfully, i want to call some other method. I thought, around will be like before+after(liek both before and after the method execution, i can intercept). Is my understanding wrong ?

Comment: Ok, let me show with code. If you put this around advice:
    around(int i): ... { System.out.println('foo');proceed(i*100);System.out.println('bar');}
on this method:
m(int i) { System.out.println(i); }
The weaver will create this code:
m(int i) { calladvice(i); }
calladvice() { System.out.println('foo'); call_body_of_m(i*100); System.out.println('bar');}
call_body_of_m(int i) { System.out.println(i); }
It is kind of like before+after but not the same since those advice types can only observe parameters at the join point, not modify them. Sorry for the formatting!